# Books describing motion of objects in fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, kinematics

I'm looking for any resources that would help me model the behavior of objects moving in fluid. My end goal is to be able to describe the motion of irregularly shaped objects in a river environment. Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: I think this is a bit too localized to be allowed here, but to get you started: take a look at the research of [this guy](http://www.mech.kth.se/mech/info_staff.jsp?ID=66)

Comment: More fluid dynamics book recommendations: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9815/2451

Comment: I really don't get how it is decided, whether a reference questions is valid or not. I'm a physicist and I had the exact same question a while ago. Just because it is not QFT, it doesn't mean that it is not valid or not needed. An excellent book on the topic is: [Computational Techniques for Multiphase Flows](http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Techniques-Multiphase-Flows-Guan/dp/0080467334).

Comment: Another valuable resource is this [master thesis in bed fluidization](http://lib.tkk.fi/Dipl/2012/urn100616.pdf).